# Не сразу выводит форму

Tags: android

Как сделать так, что бы программа выполнялась после того как на экране появятся все элементы? Если писать так, то ничего не выводится пока не истечет время.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
   }
```

Comment: вроде в onCreate() происходит только создание окна а отображение происходит после onCreate(), по крайней мере когда я вчера отлавливал баг в листАадаптер.getView() он происходил уже после отработки onCreate()

----------------------------

> программа выполнялась после того как
> на экране появятся все элементы

а что вы под этим имеете ввиду? конкретно в вашем случае что происходит?

Comment: В моем случае сначала 100 секунд белый экран, и только потом на форме появляются элементы.

Comment: Гм. Ну так уберите `sleep` и не будет этой задержки. Чего вы с его помощью хотели добиться то?

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте это

```
content.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout() {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
          content.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
      } else {
          content.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
      }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, вы ищите [`Handler.postDelayed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29).

Посмотрите [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

В зависимости от задачи, также возможно вы захотите использовать `onPause`, [`this.runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29), или `new Handler.post`.